# How to execute VBS script in Java?

Tags: java, vbscript

How to execute VBS script in Java?  What is he preferred way? I found in Internet *so many* advices, so I don't know what is better...

1.

```
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cscript //NoLogo " + file.getPath());
```

2.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript.exe " + file.getPath())
```

3.

```
String script = "C:\\work\\selenium\\chrome\\test.vbs";
String executable = "C:\\windows\\...\\vbs.exe"; 
String cmdArr [] = {executable, script};
Runtime.getRuntime ().exec (cmdArr);
```

4.

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c a.vbs");`

5.

```
Desktop#open(new File("c:/a.vbs"));
```

And It is not all.

**What kind of this to choose? I need to execute following script:**

```
If Not IsObject(application) Then
Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
Set session = connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VB scripts are typically executed using utility named `cscript`. I do not remember where this utility is located but it is definitely in path, so you can just run it directly like `cscript yourscript.vbs`. Now just use `Runtime.exec()` or `ProcessBuilder` from java.

And for your convenience avoid using back slashes in java code. Use forward slash instead. It works in windows perfectly and do not require duplications like `\\`.